# Differences between Kernel#sleep and Thread.stop

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Are:

- `Kernel#sleep` used without an argument, and
- `Thread.stop`

equivalent? If not, what differences are there?

Answer (score 1):

i think that you are asking if calling `sleep` or `stop` within a running thread are equivalent. i would say that, yes, it's semantically the same, but they call different lowlevel functions:

```
stop -> rb_thread_sleep_deadly();
sleep -> rb_thread_sleep_forever();
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how those C-level functions are different?